# Spatial DB lookup to image DB

Tags: postgis, query

I am working on a library project for rectifying old map imaging on a map. The images are in tiff and jpeg formats.

After rectifying the images I want to save the geographical information in a PostGIS database, while the image itself will remain in another DB, in the same format.

What methods I can use to query the images DB with geographic data based query? (i.e. polygon search on the map will retrieve all rectified maps on that area)

Comment: You are looking for spatial relationship functions e.g. [ST_Relate](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Relate.html) or [ST_Intersects](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html). This [tutorial](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html) is a good starting point for that topic.

Answer (score -1):

For each image store the envelope or bounding box. You can use gdaltindex to create a shapefile or PKTOOLS And store that in the database. Look at IIIF and leafletjs plugins Klokantech has developed several libraries for their oldmaps app and website